# Expectation of Multivariate sample variance

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis, expected-value, mean

Given $\{X_i\}$ a sample i.i.d. observations of a $J$-dimensional random variable with $E(X_i)=\mu\in\mathbb{R}^J,V(X_i)=\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{J\times J}$.

**Is it true that:**
$$
E\left[(X_i-\bar{X}_n)(X_i-\bar{X}_n)'\right]=\Sigma\equiv E\left[(X_i-\mu)(X_i-\mu)'\right]
$$

Is there a compact proof for this in the case it's true? 
Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I think you still need  the correction($\frac{1}{n-1}$) as in univariate case  to get the unbiased estimation.

Comment: @DeepNorth is correct, because this *is* the univariate case--repeated $J\times J$ times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

As a very simple counter example, consider the univariate case with a single sample. Then the left side of your equation reduces down to

$E[(x - x)^2] = 0$

The right side of your equation would then reduce down to

$E[(x - \mu)^2] = \sigma^2$

Comment: I believe you mean "one-sample" rather than univariate.

Comment: @whuber: actually, I do mean univariate, as in $J = 1$. But how the OP stated the problem implies one sample, as I understand it.

Comment: I think most people would understand the presence of an index on "$X$", as written in the question, as indicating a sample of more than one.

Comment: @whuber: to help clarify, I added the note of a single sample